# Can I put a conditional into an INNER JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two type of users that I'm saving them in two different tables, I need to select the data of this user depending the type, this is my query:

```
SELECT user_data_bis.name, user_data_bis.surname, 
       user_data_bis.avatarimage, user.externalid, user.type // User's Data
FROM user_wall_likes 
INNER JOIN user
    ON user.internalid = user_wall_likes.owner
INNER JOIN  (CASE user.type
                  WHEN user.type=0
                  THEN
                      (
                      SELECT name, owner, surname, avatarimage
                      FROM user_data
                      ) user_data_bis
                  WHEN user.type=1
                  THEN
                      (
                      SELECT name, "" AS surname, owner, icon AS avatarimage
                      FROM university_data
                      WHERE isdelete=0
                      ) user_data_bis
             END)
             ON user_data_bis.owner = user.internalid 
             WHERE user_wall_likes.wallid="619fd58836c9a826b9eafb4b4e81da24" 
                   AND user_wall_likes.isdeleted=0
             LIMIT 5
```

Note: When it say `user_wall_likes.wallid="619fd58836c9a826b9eafb4b4e81da24`, this varchar is an example of one columns in my DB

But when I execute this query, it shows me:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE user.type WHEN user.type=0' at line 6

Is there some  method to extract the data from the table depending of the variable in this case `user.type`?

Comment: Try do select case ...your subquery...

Comment: To clarify, by "two type of users that I'm saving them in two different tables" do you mean you only have the tables user and user_data_bis or is there a third table (such as user_data_gov)?

Comment: @toonice Something like that,  I have the User table with its UserData table, and then the University table with its UniversityData table

Answer (score 0):

You would accomplish this with two `left join`s and `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT coalesce(ud.name, unv.name) as name,
       coalesce(ud.surname, unv.surname) as surname,
       coalesce(ud.avatarimage, unv.avatarimage) as avatarimage,
       u.externalid, u.type    -- User's Data
FROM user_wall_likes uld INNER JOIN
     user u
     ON u.internalid = uwl.owner LEFT JOIN
     user_data ud
     ON u.type = 0 AND ud.owner = u.internalid LEFT JOIN
     university_data unv
     ON u.type = 1 AND unv.owner = u.internalid
WHERE uwl.wallid = '619fd58836c9a826b9eafb4b4e81da24' AND uwl.isdeleted = 0
LIMIT 5;
```

Note that you would normally have an `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`.